# How to check if an incident happened during a time frame in C#?

Tags: c#

I am developing software that adds if a button is clicked 5 times, a variable is incremented by '1'

IF A then B++

everything is good, but now I want the system to reset its counter if that 5 times did not happen within 10 seconds. I.e the speed of clicking matters.

If I click too slow, the increment should not happen even though I clicked 5 times as it exceeds that 10 secs period.

Any suggestion?

Comment: add a timer. have it tick every 10 seconds. in the tick event handler, check if the click count is divisible by 5. if not, reset it.

Comment: Basically, you want to keep track of when the button was first clicked and then check it against that variable when the last click you care about happens. But actually, you want to record when the "5 clicks ago" clicked happens so you need that information about every click.

Comment: `Timer` is a given. Depending on your level of skill, you might also want to check out [the Observer pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/observer-design-pattern).

Comment: It is not necessary to use a timer for this problem, unless there are other requirements than those stated here (for example an update to UI if the time expires). Upon click: compare current time to a stored time variable (this will be `DateTime.MinValue` for the first click). If difference is greater than 10 seconds, set counter to 1 and set stored time to current time; otherwise, just increase counter by one. If counter reaches 5, execute increment of `B` variable, reset stored time to `DateTime.MinValue`.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done much nicer but it should work:

```
 DateTime time = new DateTime();//time of first click
 int counter = 0;

void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(counter == 0)
    {time = DateTime.Now}
    else if(counter == 5)
    {
         if( DateTime.Now.Subtract(time).Duration().Seconds <= 10)
         {/*Do some cool stuff*/}
         else
         {counter = -1;}
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
const int ClicksRequired = 5;
readonly TimeSpan ClickTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);

Queue<DateTime> _clicks = new Queue<DateTime>();

private void clickTarget_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    _clicks.Enqueue(currentTime);

    if (_clicks.Count == ClicksRequired)
    {
        var firstTime = _clicks.Dequeue();
        if (currentTime - firstTime <= ClickTimeSpan)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
            _clicks.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

I use Queue to keep track of clicks because you don't know which mouse click will actually be the first click until you have five clicks in the time window.  You need to know the time of the fifth click back in time and that click changes with each subsequent click.

I use MouseUp instead of Click because Click might not fire the correct number of times if clicks occur within the system double-click interval (because those get routed to DoubleClick).